# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: token is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have an Angular 8 app and working nice in dev mode, but if i do 'ng serve --prod' it's compiling without error but when launching the app i got this error in console :

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: token is undefined
>   getOrCreateInjectable/bloomHash<@http://localhost:4200/main.cf6fe5006f05f980ad3b.js:1:249524
>   getOrCreateInjectable@http://localhost:4200/main.cf6fe5006f05f980ad3b.js:1:249614
>   get@http://localhost:4200/main.cf6fe5006f05f980ad3b.js:1:254632
>   PlayerComponent@http://localhost:4200/main.cf6fe5006f05f980ad3b.js:1:726594
>   factory@http://localhost:4200/main.cf6fe5006f05f980ad3b.js:1:728189
>   getNodeInjectable@http://localhost:4200/main.cf6fe5006f05f980ad3b.js:1:253710
>   ...

Do you have an idea on how determine what's going wrong ?
Reading the error i have my PlayerComponent called but there is nothing special in

```
import { Game, IsoScene } from 'src/app/tars/classes';
import { NavigatorService } from 'src/app/tars/services';
import { DataProvider, ElementProvider } from 'src/app/tars/providers';
import { ElementProvider as POCElementProvider } from 'src/app/services/element.provider';
import { IsoPlayerScene } from 'src/app/classes/scenes/iso';
import { InteractionsMenu } from 'src/app/interfaces';
import { DataProviderFactory } from 'src/app/services/dataProviders/factory.service';
import { OnReadyRenderer2DEvent, Interaction } from 'src/app/tars/interfaces';
import { TitleScene } from 'src/app/classes/scenes/title';

@Component({
  selector: 'tars-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.scss']
})
export class PlayerComponent {
  private rendererW: number;
  private rendererH: number;

  public get rendererHeight(): number {
    return this.rendererH;
  }

  public get rendererWidth(): number {
    return this.rendererW;
  }

  private game: Game;
  private navigatorService: NavigatorService;
  private dataProvider: DataProvider;
  private elementProvider: ElementProvider;

  private isoPlayer: IsoPlayerScene;
  public menuStructure: InteractionsMenu;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.navigatorService = injector.get(NavigatorService);

    this.dataProvider = injector.get(DataProvider);
    this.dataProvider.set(injector.get(DataProviderFactory.factory()));

    this.elementProvider = injector.get(ElementProvider);
    this.elementProvider.set(injector.get(POCElementProvider));

    this.resetInteractionsMenu();
  }

  rendererOnReady(event: OnReadyRenderer2DEvent) {
    // Create the game object
    this.game = new Game(this.injector, event.context);
    this.game.onLoaded.subscribe((res: boolean) => {
      // Ask current client size
      this.refreshClientSize();
      // Run the game (when ready inside)
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.game.run());
    });

    // Specific link
    this.isoPlayer = new IsoPlayerScene(this.injector, {name: 'world'}, event.context);
    this.isoPlayer.onInteractionsMenu.subscribe((structure: InteractionsMenu) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        if (structure) {
          this.menuStructure = structure;
        } else {
          this.resetInteractionsMenu();
        }
      });
    });

    this.game.load([
      this.isoPlayer,
      new TitleScene(this.injector, {name: 'title'}, event.context),
      new IsoScene(this.injector, {name: 'loader'}, event.context),
    ], 'title', 'loader');
  }

  // Listen the window resize event
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event: any) {
    this.refreshClientSize();
    this.resetInteractionsMenu();
  }

  // Get the window/body size to set the graph size
  public refreshClientSize() {
    const browserSize = this.navigatorService.getClientSizeFromBrowser();
    this.rendererW = browserSize.width;
    this.rendererH = browserSize.height;
    this.navigatorService.setClientSize(browserSize.width, browserSize.height);
  }

  // Keyboard management
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyPress(event: any) {
    this.navigatorService.keyDown(event);
  }

  private resetInteractionsMenu() {
    this.menuStructure = {
      interactions: [],
      screenCoord: { screenX: 0, screenY: 0 }
    };
  }

  // Do interaction when menu selection is done and reset menu
  menuOnSelect(interaction: Interaction) {
    this.isoPlayer.doInteraction(interaction);
    this.resetInteractionsMenu();
  }
}
```

Like i said, it's working in dev and i don't understand why --prod give this result.

**EDIT:**

It seems to be the line `this.dataProvider.set(injector.get(DataProviderFactory.factory()));` about the factory with the code below that break on --prod

```
@Injectable()
export class DataProviderFactory {
  public static factory() {
    if (environment.dataOrigin === DataOrigin.Fake) {
      return Faker;
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

If i replace `DataProviderFactory.factory()` by Faker directly it's working.
I read about some problem with Ivy and creatInjector but it seems not working.

Any idea ?

Comment: create a build using ng build --prod --optimizer you will get exactly where you get error

Comment: For me the error comes from `bloomHash` but nothing sure. Try the comment above and see if you can get some more details on it.

Comment: With '$ ng build --prod --optimization' I got 3 warnings on unused files (like env.prod.ts) but no more details.

Comment: Question edited with more details, thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of --prod, DataProviderFactory return a null value that the injector can't handle for tokenisation. So it fail, my bad. But the diplayed exception is not at all clear and helpfull. Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I stumpled upon this question, because I had the same error.

In my case it was a stupid typo
instead of `marked.parse(text)` I called `marked.parser(text)`

Might help anyone with the same cause who finds this questions as well